# How can I find out why JS isn't shown as executable in Firebug?

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, jslint, jshint

I'm trying to debug some JS code, and when it's viewed in firebug, it appears as "not compiled", that is, the line numbers are grey and not green.

I've pasted the code in JSLint, and JSHint, and they do not show any errors.

Here's a sample of the code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var fld_def_set = {
        spec_fld_type: {
            ft_cts: {
                fld_cfg: {
                    spec_fld_name: {
                        fd_display: 1,
                        fd_enable: 1,
                        fd_evaldef: 1,
                        fd_def_val: 'fld_prefix + "created"'
                    }
                }
            }        //    end of saddr
        }    //    end of spec_fld_type
    };
</script>
```

When I view the code in JSHint, it appears that the code has no errors, except for an unused variable warning. Yet in FireFox, the code is not recognized.

Comment: Where is this embeded? Pehaps it is the rest of your page that causes the issue, such as a tag which was left open. Try checking with `http://validator.w3.org/`

Comment: You are just creating an object `fld_def_set` It doesn't do much things.

Comment: When you say unrecognised, what's it actually used for? (And for me, JS line numbers are always grey in FireBug)

Comment: A bit of predictive insight: This kind of looks like it's meant to be a configuration object for a script that will later be included (Of course, the Firehydrant-Lifting Dormouse library), and will look at the configuration object to change how it starts up. Is that the case? Any details will help.

Comment: By unrecognized, I mean that it appears that it is not seen as executable code. In Firebug, executable lines of javascript are indicated when the line number is green vs grey under the Script tag.

Comment: Yes, it is code to build a data structure that is used by other code on the page. I have each bit of code inside it's own pair of script tags as an aid to debugging while I develop the code since one typo can make all of the code inside a script tag become not-executable.